# Animating a PasswordChar in wpf?

Tags: wpf, animation, adorner, adornerdecorator

Is there a way to animate an adorner on the scaleTransform property so that the ellipse appears from a slight scale to another scale.
I have the following code in my `OnRender()` method:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Black, null, new Point(10, 10), 6, 6);
}

void AnimAdorner_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation d = new DoubleAnimation(0, 20, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    this.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, d);
    this.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, d);
}
```